# Modsecurity configuration (to avoid false positive SQL injection attacks)

Tags: post, sql-injection, mod-security

I have a form which contains a field which can legitimately contain strings (mathematical expressions) such as (A-B)*C or (A*B)*(C*D). However the Modsecurity security feature on the server prevents the form from being submitted and posted to the database because it interprets those strings as SQL injection attacks. Can someone lead me in the right direction on how I can configure an exception list to allow those by adding the fingerprint or unique_id? This is very unfamiliar territory for me, so if you could dumb it down for me, that would be great. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I called my hosting company and gave them the ID corresponding to the error log (341245) and they took care of adding that ID to the exception list. The string (A-B)*C no longer triggers the false positive. :-)